# Why is Tom toothless in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter, the publican  of the Leaky Cauldron is described as toothless. Why is this, given that (as Hermione shows) magic can regrow teeth?

Comment: We are not told, but perhaps there are curses that prevent the regrowth of teeth even by magic means.

Comment: Correct, @MichaelStern, we see that a cursed ear cannot regrow (the holy George), so perhaps cursed teeth also can't grow back

Comment: Curses, sure. Then why can't Harry's eyes be fixed? No anoptometric curses there.

Comment: Perhaps he just ... likes being toothless? It might also not be meant literally, sometimes toothless can simply mean harmless.

Comment: @elemtilas There is a theory that Harry's eyes _were_ cursed when Voldemort tried to kill him (i.e. the same curse that caused Harry to become an accidental (not actual) horcrux)

Comment: There's a better example than Hermione's teeth (which were never missing) — Deathly Hallows, Fallen Warrior. Harry's tooth has been regrown by Ted Tonks. It was knocked out physically rather than by a curse, but still regrown from missing.

Answer (score 5):

Magic doesn't seem to be able to reverse the effects of ordinary *ageing*. Noting that Tom has been the barman since the late 1930s, which means that he must be at least into his 80s at the time of the first novel, if not older.

> A little man in a top hat was talking to the **old barman, who was quite bald and looked like a gummy walnut.**

It's likely that Tom lost his teeth simply as a result of poor tooth hygiene and normal senescence. You might want to note that there's at least one other wizard missing his teeth, an equally elderly Grindlewald.

> At once, Harry’s scar felt as though it had split open again. His true surroundings vanished: he was Voldemort, and the skeletal wizard before him [Grindlewald] was laughing toothlessly at him.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>

---

Other examples of non-reversible ageing include elderly Amos Diggory using a wheelchair in Cursed Child.

[image]

And older Albus Dumbledore wearing glasses.

[image]

Comment: Your answer brings up an interesting conundrum between the operation of magic as JKR originally conceived it, how its concept has grown and the human body and how it works. So far, I think you come closest to an answer, yet in the end, I think we've just moved farther away from understanding the underlying fundamentals of what's happening.

Comment: Grindelwald was imprisoned without a wand, and not exactly housed in the best of conditions, so I'm not sure he's necessarily an example of magic being unable to regrow teeth. Even if that were possible it likely wouldn't have been an option for him personally, as he couldn't cast the spell himself and his jailers aren't likely to cast it on him.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Prisoners are usually afforded good medical care. Them dying is seen as a failing on the part of the state

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, I'm pretty sure that prisoners at Azkaban are afforded real good medical care. Grindelwald wasn't in Azkaban, but I don't think Grindelwald, being a tyrannical monster, was afforded any kind of luxury beyond keeping him alive in the worst conditions possible.

Comment: @Roberto - They had dentists and doctors at Spandau

Comment: @Valorum I think it's pretty much evidenced that in Azkaban the prisoners are left to die, with minimal care. Definitely not doctors. Don't try to compare muggle prisons to magical prisons, because the Wizarding World seems to think that human rights aren't important.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist -- From what little we've seen of how prisoners in Azkaban end up looking like, and from the absolutely deplorable and backward nature of the MoM, I doubt very much inmates get much more than a cold, seadamp cell with all the dementors they want. I don't think healthcare is in their vocabulary. I doubt MACUSA is any more enlightened.

Answer (score 5):

Because we are not shown that teeth *can* be regrown.

Hermione did not lose her teeth she was struck with a Densaugeo spell and...

> It wasn't a pretty sight. Hermione's front teeth — already larger than average — were now growing at an alarming rate; she was looking more and more like a beaver as they elongated, past her bottom lip, towards her chin — panic-stricken, she felt them, and let out a terrified cry.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</sub>

When Madam Pomfrey was shrinking her teeth back down, Hermione simply allowed to be shrunk further than their previous actual size.

> Well... when I went up to Madam Pomfrey to get them shrunk, she held up a mirror and told me to stop her when they were back to how they normally were," she said. "And I just... let her carry on a bit." She smiled even more widely. "Mum and Dad won't be too pleased. I've been trying to persuade them to let me shrink them for ages, but they wanted me to carry on with my braces. (ibid)

One can assume that once Tom actually lost his teeth, for whatever reason, they could not be grown back.

---

A little real science that may explain why we see bone regrowing (i.e. Skele-Gro) and not teeth.

> The exterior of bones consists of periosteum, a dense, smooth, slippery membrane that lines the outer surface of most bones , except at the joints of long bones, which instead consist of slimy hyaline cartilage. Periosteum contains osteoblasts, or cells that can manufacture new bone growth and repair.
>
> Tooth enamel, unfortunately, doesn't have the same regenerative powers. Unlike bones, teeth cannot heal themselves or grow back together if they are broken. When a bone fractures , new bone cells rush in to fill the gap and repair the break, but a cracked or a broken tooth can require a root canal or even total extraction.
>
> <sub>[*Why Are Teeth Not Considered Bones?* By Remy Melina March 18, 2011](https://www.livescience.com/33130-why-are-teeth-not-considered-bones.html)</sub>

In my theory Skele-Gro may simply activate and accelerate the process of the bone cells and osteoblasts.

Comment: Yet we know bone can easily, if disgustingly, be regrown. While it's true we're "not shown", the inference is logical that teeth ought to be either magically repaired (if broken) or replaced (if lost) (unless otherwise cursed). We're not shown a great many things about the WW, yet inferences and assumptions can still be made.

Comment: @elemtilas Teeth are not bones and do not have the natural regenerative qualities found in bones.

Comment: I know they are not bones, and I never said they were bones! They are related structures, however.

Comment: @elemtilas So why would teeth behave anything like bones, magically repaired or not?

Comment: Because they are human tissue and they are similar, though not identical, to bone in their composition. We know there are many spells and concoctions that can repair ghastly wounds -- skelegro, episkey, vulnera sanentur, etc., etc. We know there's a whole magical hospital that can take care of a wide variety of ailments and injuries. It simply follows reason that teeth should be magically treatable, rather than to assume that they are special and not treatable, fixable, or replaceable.. The very fact that Madam Pomfrey can trivially reduce their physical size means that dental tissues are...

Comment: If teeth couldn't be replaced, this product would be quite dangerous; https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Tooth_Splintering_Strong_Mints

Comment: (cont) ... magically malleable. Growing a new tooth from the ravaged remains of one that's broken off or from the remaining tissues in the jaw follows from the underlying science she is relying on.

Comment: @elemtilas yes, but all those things the body can already naturally heal; bone, skin, etc. Teeth can not. Resizing and object is not the same a recreating it.

Comment: Yes, maybe if Tom had even a tiny sliver of tooth left it could be resized and reshaped to resemble a normal tooth, but once the whole tooth is gone there is no source material to work off of.

Comment: I doubt she was using engorgio, which resizes and object. In order to change the size of a tooth, you'd have to either add matter into the structural matrix of the tooth, or in Hermione's case, remove said matter from the structural matrix. If you can do that, you can easily, perhaps trivially, fix a fractured tooth.

Comment: @Valorum I take film props with a grain of salt. But yes they would be!

Comment: That doesn't follow! Don't forget that Professor Lockhart actually ended up *removing* Harry's bone after the quidditch incident. (Of course "we are not shown", but all that seems to be left over is muscle, and perhaps collagen and other soft tissues (nerves, vessels, etc.) Yet skelegro grew an entirely new bone (well, two actually) where none remained. It doesn't follow that one can entirely replace a discrete structure, while another similar structure can not be so replaced from scratch.

Comment: @elemtilas It was probably the ["Teeth-straightening spell"](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Teeth-straightening_spell)

Comment: Teeth straightening spell: interesting, but I'd argue that it's just another data point in favour of teeth being magically malleable. And also an object lesson in why it's very dangerous engaging in magical surgery of any kind. SUMMATION: I concur with you that "we are not shown". However, I don't think that's enough to hang a good answer on. For me, I think we'd need some kind of definitive statement one way or the other: either that "these parts of the body simply can't be fixed for XYZ reasons" or else "Tom was a special case for ABC reasons".

Comment: Doesn't Ted Tonks re-grow Harry's tooth after it gets knocked out at the beginning of DH?

Answer (score 1):

There could be plenty of reasons for this-

1. Difficulty - Not everyone could be so talented as to grow back teeth from nothing. You can't just grow teeth from nothing. Even if it is possible it has to be very delicate work requiring professional skills.

To be a healer you need N.E.W.T.s of at least grade 'Exceeds Expectations' in the subjects of Transfiguration, Potions, Charms, Herbology and Defence Against the Dark Arts, which isn't an easy thing to do.

This brings us to my second point.

2. Cost - It surely would cost a lot considering it takes professionals to do it. Just because there is magic doesn't mean everything is possible. And Tom is never shown as a rich guy.
3. Just why?- A lot of people even in real life are toothless or have a very fixable oral problem. They just don't see the fuss about this harmless problem, nor do they care. Come on, he runs a very busy hotel, he can't just waste a day at St Mungo's.

The example you are referring to is a fairly uncomplicated matter requiring a simple shrinking spell, while Tom's case is different.